# html/bootstrap - checkbox and radio in the one input-group

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, radio-button

What I'm trying to do is make it so that you can either select option 1 OR any number of the other options. So option 1 should be "radio" and the others should be normal "checkboxes".

My code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label>Presentation:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="presentation" id="presentation-0" value="correct">
       Option 1
    <input type="checkbox" name="presentation" id="presentation-1" value="Incorrect1">
       Option 2
    <input type="checkbox" name="presentation" id="presentation-2" value="Incorrect2">
       Option 3
    <input type="checkbox" name="presentation" id="presentation-3" value="Incorrect3">
       Option 4    
</div>
```

If I do it like this, you can still select Option 1 at the same time as the other options though. Anyone know how I can get the desired result? (so option 1 becomes unselected when you select another option / options 2-4 get unselected when you select option 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it  by add attribute and remove attribute jquery function.
add 2 class, for example add class="radio" in your radio input, and add class=check in your checkbox input then try bellow jquery code.

```
$('.radio').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    $('.check').removeAttr('checked');
})
$('.check').click(function(){
   $(this).attr('checked', 'checked'); 
   $('.radio').removeAttr('checked');
})
```